# How can I find 3d parametric functions that create unbroken loops that repeat periodically with no breaks?

Tags: continuity, 3d, parametric

I'm learning to make visual effects in Unity's VFX Graph and I want to find a way to make a continuous curve 'cause I think it'd look cool. I did some googling and found some image examples, but no complete equations.

Example:

[image: A parametric function that creates a closed loop]

Is there any general strategy I could use to construct/discover 3d parametric functions that create closed loops? Is this a studied topic in mathematics? If so, what keywords should I look for to find more info?

Comment: if $x(t)$, $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are functions of $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$, then they repeat every $2\pi$. So, for example, $(x,y,z)=(\cos(t), \sin(t)+4+\cos(2*t), \log(4-\cos(3t+\frac\pi8)))$ will be a closed curve, with $t\in[0,2\pi)$. 

If you want a surface, you need $x(u,v)$ etc to be periodic in both $u$ and $v$, so, functions of $\cos(u)$, $\cos(v)$, $\sin(u)$ and $\sin(v)$.

Comment: If you want a tube around a curve $\mathbf{r}(t)$, one way is to find two unit normal vectors to the surface, and then use them to trace a circle around each point $r(t)$, to get a parametrisation $\mathbf{r}(t) + \rho\mathbf{n}_1\cos(u) + \rho\mathbf{n}_2\sin(u)$. For example, if $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a circle $(5\cos(t), 5\sin(t), 0)$, two suitable normal vectors are $(0,0,1)$ and $(\sin(t), -\cos(t), 0)$. Then, choosing $\rho=2$ so the tube is quite fat, we get $(x,y,z)=(5\cos(t),5\sin(t),0)+(0,0,2\cos(u)) + (2\sin(t)\sin(u), -2\cos(t)\sin(u), 0)$, which is the parametric equation of a torus.

Comment: In general, you can find $\mathbf{n}_1$ as follows: (A) choose some arbitrary vector $\mathbf v$ that you know is never parallel to $\mathbf{r}(t)$. (B) differentiate $\mathbf{r}(t)$ to get the vector parallel to the curve $\mathbf{r}^\prime(t)$, (C) find the cross product $\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{r}^\prime(t)$ (D) normalise this to get $\mathbf{n}_1(t)$. Then, you can find $\mathbf{n}_2(t)$ using the same procedure, but using $\mathbf{n}_1$ or just $\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{r}^\prime$ in place of $\mathbf{v}$. The algebra gets very messy quickly.

Comment: @MichaelHartley Excellent! That's exactly what I needed, thanks :)